# Extending WorkflowServiceHost with custom endpoints

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

Is it possible to extend the **WorkflowServiceHost** with custom endpoints in the same way endpoints are added to the **ServiceHost** class? For instance, an endpoint implementing the interface *ICustomTracking* with *BasicHttpBinding*.

I'm looking for a solution using code, not the config file.

Any idea?